# Count consecutive days in SQL

Tags: sql, date, google-bigquery

I have a dataset with names of people who enrolled for the gym with the dates they actually went to the gym. I want to count the number of days they consecutively entered the gym. The dataset looks like below.

| Name | Date |
| --- | --- |
| Ally | 1/1/2021 |
| Ally | 1/2/2021 |
| Ally | 1/3/2021 |
| Ally | 1/5/2021 |
| Ally | 1/7/2021 |
| Brian | 1/12/2021 |
| Brian | 1/13/2021 |
| Brian | 1/16/2021 |
| Brian | 1/21/2021 |
| Brian | 1/22/2021 |

Here we know Ally went to the gym 3 days consecutively (1/1/2021-1/3/2021) and Brian went 4 days (1/12/2021-1/13/2021 and 1/21/2021-1/22/2021). I want the final result to look like this.

| Name | Count |
| --- | --- |
| Ally | 3 |
| Ally | 1 |
| Ally | 1 |
| Brian | 2 |
| Brian | 1 |
| Brian | 2 |

Is there a way to do this in SQL?

Comment: I removed the inconsistent database tags.  Tag only with the database you are really using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subtract a incrementing value from the dates to get a constant when the dates are incrementing by one.  The rest is just aggregation.

Because you have not clearly specified a database, I'll use standard SQL syntax:

```
select name, count(*), min(date), max(date)
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by name order by date) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
group by name, date - seqnum * interval '1 day'
order by name, min(date);
```

This should work in Postgres (which is close to Standard SQL).  In SQL Server, it would be:

```
group by name, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date)
```

Comment: I am working on bigquery. looks like there is a syntax difference for that?

Comment: I changed the groupby block to 
"group by name, date_add(date, interval -seqnum day)" 
It now works with bigquery. 
Thanks a lot for this wonderful solution. Cheers!

Comment: In SQL would this have an overflow with large databases? say seqnum is 3million.